# How to update onlineMeeting - Graph API Microsoft teams meeting?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to insert a teams meeting link into our emails that are sent out. I want to call the api to generate a teams meeting link, WHICH I can do. However, how do I update this meeting if the time needs to be changed or if new participants are added? I can't find anything on the Microsoft Graph API documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

- Only see get,create,delete options

Answer (score 0):

Currently only [create meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) event is exposed by Graph API.

Comment: I think you meant to direct him to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http. The url you provided shows the create calendar methods as opposed to create onlinemeeting.

Comment: Yes, The one I shared is a outlook exchange API which creates meeting in calendar.

Answer (score 0):

`PATCH /beta/me/onlineMeetings/{meetingId}` appears to work for me, but `/PATCH` on the `v1.0` endpoint returns an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "NotImplemented",
    "message": "PATCH onlineMeeting is only supported in graph beta",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-07-12T07:50:58",
      "request-id": "0a1824d8-e329-452f-bc73-988d1de832ed"
    }
  }
}
```